# CSS position for sliding upward div

Tags: css, positioning, slidetoggle

I would like to position a dynamically generated div directly above a button (higher in the page, not Z-index).  When the button is clicked, I want to reveal the div with a reverse jQuery `slideToggle()`.

I have set up an example in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sablefoste/YWnJE/30/

I am close, but I can't seem to position the reveal to appear directly above the button.  I am able to get it to slide upward with by using my CSS `position:absolute; left:0;bottom:0;`  following the first example in http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions/.

If I change the `left:0; bottom:0;` to something else, I can position it correctly until the browser window is resized.

Is there a way to do this without brute force (specifically, identifying the top of the `#storiesbutton`, and jQuery to reposition the bottom of the `#storylist`)?

I appreciate any ideas!  Thank you!

Comment: Just so I understand, you want the div with the "title goes here" to be hidden until the "stories" button is clicked, at which point it will appear sliding up above that same button. Is that correct?

Comment: @DigTheDoug, yes, that is correct.  When creating the fiddle, I didn't start with the storylist hidden.  I should have included `$('#storylist').hide()` along with the standard `$(document).on("ready", (function(e)
 {}`.  I will update the fiddle to show it.

Comment: As a side note, you can put a `display:none` on the element itself rather than running `.hide()` on it first thing.

Comment: Great sidenote, @DigTheDoug!  I will do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going on pure guesswork here, but my thing is that you want the menu to appear above the button. I've tried it using

```
var list = $('#storylist'),
    button = $('#storiesbutton'),
    speed = 500;

list.hide().css('bottom', button.css('top'))
    .css('margin-top', list.outerHeight() * -1);
```

So the position of the stories is set on load based on the position of the button and the height of the list.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qt3LE/

Like I said though, I'm not 100% on what you are after. This may help with the positioning.

Also I used `$.toggle(function(){}, function(){})` rather that toggleSlide as you have more control over the individual toggles.

Comment: This is the "brute force" method I was trying to avoid, but it appears to be the only way.  I like the particular compactness of your solution, so I am choosing this as the final answer.

Answer (score 1):

So when you put `position: absolute` on that element, what you are doing it is positioning it as a fixed set of pixels according it's first non-static ancestor. In most cases and this case, that would be the body itself, which is why it was stuck at the bottom. What you want to do is constrain that absolutely positioned element inside another div so that it does not get positioned at the bottom of the page, but instead where you want it. So you would just wrap that element:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="storylist" style="display:none;">
      <ul>
           <li>
             Title 1 goes here.
           </li>
           <li>
             Title 2 goes here.
           </li>
           <li>
             Maybe a Title 3 goes here, but it is dynamically generated.
           </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

inside another div, and give that new div

```
#wrapper{
   position: relative;   
}
```

[Here's the example in a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/digthedoug/D5dFy/1/)

Comment: Thank you! This and @aayush shrestha 's answer seems to work for the vertical, but when adjusting the horizontal page width, there is still is an misalignment when resizing the browser width.  I can't think how to apply a similar strategy for width.

Comment: You should be able to apply the same horizontal styling that you use with the buttons on the container div. Either giving it a `margin: auto`, or a `text-align:center` with a `width:100%` depending on how you have the buttons positioned.

Comment: Looking at your styles again, the only way to center that element in the page like the buttons is to either give it a fixed with, or do it with javascript, unfortunately.

Comment: They aren't exactly centered (the number of buttons will vary also), but I have come to the same conclusion.  Unfortunately, brute force is the only way to locate this.  I still using the extra container wrapper, because it reduces the over-all load, so thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but if you're looking for the information to be above the button you might try removing `position:absolute`

Like this
http://jsfiddle.net/cjds/AnpzK/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  But if I do remove the absolute position, the buttons move up and down on the reveal/conceal.

Answer (score 0):

Put the buttonbar and the storyline in a container like this:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="storylist">
  <ul>
       <li>
         Title 1 goes here.
       </li>
       <li>
         Title 2 goes here.
       </li>
       <li>
         Maybe a Title 3 goes here, but it is dynamically generated.
       </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class= "buttonbar">
  <div>
    <span class="navbutton" id="librarybutton" >
        <a href ="#" title="Information">
            Information
        </a>
    </span>
    <span class="navbutton" id="storiesbutton" >
        <a href ="#">
            Stories
        </a>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

​

and here are the css for them:

```
#container {
position:relative;
background:#efefef;
}
#storylist{
height:60px;
position:absolute;
left:0;
bottom:0;
}
.buttonbar{
margin:20px 50px 20px 0;    
text-align:center;
width:100%;
position:absolute;
bottom:-60px;
}
```

I have absolute positioned the button bar AND the storyline so you could get that desired "upward sliding" action. Hope this is what you want. Here's  fiddle of what i did. http://jsfiddle.net/YWnJE/41/